# CircleCI permission denied running bash script

Tags: bash, circleci

I have a `circle.yml` file like so:

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - meteor || curl https://install.meteor.com | /bin/sh

deployment:
  production:
    branch: "master"
    commands:
      - ./deploy.sh
```

When I push to Github, I get the error:

```
/home/ubuntu/myproject/deploy.sh returned exit code 126

bash: line 1: /home/ubuntu/myproject/deploy.sh: Permission denied Action failed: /home/ubuntu/myproject/deploy.sh
```

When I run the commands that live inside `deploy.sh` outside of the file (under `commands`) everything runs fine.

Everything in the `circle.yml` file seems to be in line with the examples in the [CircleCI docs](https://circleci.com/docs/configuration#deployment).. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Several possible problems:

1. deploy.sh might not be marked as executable (`chmod +x deploy.sh` would fix this)
2. The first line of deploy.sh might not be a runnable shell...

If the first doesn't work, can we please see the contents of deploy.sh?

Comment: if you're on windows and dev locally go here to find the equivalent for powershell and/or cmd: https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html

Comment: For me I had to add this to my yml:
          command: |
           chmod +x ./scripts/generate-pipeline-config.sh
            ./scripts/generate-pipeline-config.sh

Answer (score 34):

I was having the same issue.  I added sh to the front of my commands section to get it to work.

```
deployment:
  production:
    branch: "master"
    commands:
      - sh ./deploy.sh
```

Hopefully that fix saves everyone sometime going forward.

Comment: I found that this solution works for executing the script, however using ```sh``` disables some extensions.  see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155838/shell-script-throws-a-not-found-error-when-run-from-a-sh-file-but-if-entered-ma

Comment: @eczajk So use `- bash ./deploy.sh` instead.

Answer (score 16):

Assuming you have already checked it in, use this command to flag it as executable to git:

```
git update-index --chmod=+x script.sh
```

reference:
https://www.pixelninja.me/make-script-committed-to-git-executable/

Answer (score 0):

As @palfrey says the script is probably not marked as executable, and sometimes it seems to be marked wrong on deployment even when you have previously run `chmod +x` on your script at your local machine. *(Why? I don't know. If someone does please enlighten me!)*

Here is a general command to use to ensure your scripts are always marked as executable. This assumes they are all located in a `/home/ubuntu/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/scripts` directory and all have a `.sh` extension. If your directory(s) is(are) different, edit to use your directory instead.

Since all my scripts [*source*](https://superuser.com/a/46146/46038) a shared script *(`shared.sh`)* at the top of each script that are called by `circle.yml` I add the following code to `shared.sh` which ensures all scripts are marked as executable:

```
SCRIPTS="/home/ubuntu/${CIRCLE_PROJECT_REPONAME}/scripts"
find "${SCRIPTS}" | grep "\.sh$" | xargs chmod +x
```

Works like a charm. :-)